# Draggable positioning saved in cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

So I have a div, cguts, that has visibility toggled using jquery and is draggable on the screen. I have managed to figure out how to use cookies to get the visibility to be persistent, but I can't seem to get a handle on how to get the div's position to also be persistent throughout the site.

The following code works for everything except for saving the position of the div from one page to the next.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
        var cookieName = 'cvis';

        function setCookie(key, value) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + 31536000000); //1 year 
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
        }

        function getCookie(key) {
            var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
        }
        if (getCookie(cookieName) === '1') {
            $('#cguts').show();
            $('#cguts').draggable(function(event, ui) {
             var currentPos = $(this).position();
             var currentTop = Math.round(currentPos.top);

             // save cookie when stopped dragging
             $.cookie('position' + $(this).index('div').toString(), currentTop.toString());});
        } else if (getCookie(cookieName) === '0') {
            $('#cguts').hide();
        } else {
            setCookie(cookieName, '1');
            $('#cguts').show();
            $('#cguts').draggable(function(event, ui) {
             var currentPos = $(this).position();
             var currentTop = Math.round(currentPos.top);

             // save cookie when stopped dragging
             $.cookie('position' + $(this).index('div').toString(), currentTop.toString());});
        }
        $('.click').on('click', function () {
            if ($('#cguts').is(':visible')) {
                $('#cguts').fadeOut(300);
                setCookie(cookieName, '0');
            } else {
                $('#cguts').fadeIn(300);
                $('#cguts').draggable(function(event, ui) {
             var currentPos = $(this).position();
             var currentTop = Math.round(currentPos.top);

             // save cookie when stopped dragging
             $.cookie('position' + $(this).index('div').toString(), currentTop.toString());});
                setCookie(cookieName, '1');
            }
        });
    });
```

My question now is what am I doing wrong? I suspect the issue is in the cookie coding within draggable, but I'm officially lost...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/k414mtmt/2/

```
    $('#cguts').draggable({

    drag: function(event, ui) {

    var currentPos = $(this).position();
    var currentTop = Math.round(currentPos.top);

    // save cookie when stopped dragging
    setCookie('position' + $(this).index('div').toString(), currentTop.toString());
  }
});
```

[image]
 hope this help..:)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up approaching the matter from a different direction, so I thought I would share what ended up being my solution.

I added the following to the beginning of the file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     if ($.cookie("cvispos") != undefined) {
         var unwrapped = window.JSON.parse($.cookie("cvispos"));
         var left = window.JSON.parse($.cookie("cvispos")).left;
         var top = window.JSON.parse($.cookie("cvispos")).top;
         $("#cguts").css("left", left + "px");
         $("#cguts").css("top", top + "px");
     }
 });
```

And then changed my draggable value to:

```
$( "#cguts" ).draggable({ stop: function (event, ui) {
         $.cookie("cvispos", window.JSON.stringify(ui.position));
     }
     });
```

And it worked like a charm.